# Conditional code to integrate a multilingual form

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I am a complete noob in codes etc. I am building a website in WordPress (with Elementor) and I would like to integrate a multilingual Contact form from Hubspot based on the language that the visitor will choose.I tried different things but I was not able to solve this. I believe I need to say something like : If the visitor chooses EN and is using [if lte IE 8], use this form OR if the visitor choses FR, then use that code.

Can anybody suggest anything for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you need to learn more Javascript / Jquery.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.